# Xdebug and Webgrind couldn't get to work

Tags: apache, zend-framework, xampp, xdebug

I installed xdebug and webgrind on windows xampp 1.7.7 using this link: [link](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/10/php-xdebug-webgrind-installation/) . On going to  http:// localhost/webgrind gives something as below instead of showing profiled script.No dropdown menu or something to select.

```
Select a cachegrind file above
(looking in C:\xampp\htdocs\webgrind\tmp/ for files matching /^cachegrind.out..+..+$/)
```

But I have 2 files in tmp folder starting with cachegrind.out names.

My settings in (xampp/php/php.ini) are

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\htdocs\webgrind\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
```

webgrind/config.php settings

```
static $storageDir  = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webgrind\tmp';
static $profilerDir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webgrind\tmp';
```

I tried with these too

```
static $storageDir = '';
static $profilerDir = '/tmp';
```

But no result. How can I get it to work?

Comment: I was having the same problem. In the end, I discovered that the path in `webgrind/config.php` was incorrect (I had duplicated part of the path). Fixing that fixed the problem and it started working. Also, try escaping the slashes in your `webgrind.php` path: `'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\webgrind\\tmp'`

Answer (score 0):

I got this accidentally, playing with values in xampp/php/php.ini file.
Here is the thing change value of `xdebug.profiler_append` from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same pb that took a long day having xampp 1.7.7 in my windows 7 OS i found that the

php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.3-vc9.dll was bad even it was php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.3-vc9.exe in the first download 
 after a look at php.ini i found the good default xdebug just here with extra lignes so i delete 
the semi-colonnes ;

****[XDebug] zend_extension = "C:\Programs\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

xdebug.auto_trace 

; Type: boolean, Default value: 0 

; When this setting is set to on, the tracing of function calls will be enabled just before the 

; script is run. This makes it possible to trace code in the auto_prepend_file. 

;xdebug.auto_trace = 0****

; xdebug.collect_includes 

; Type: boolean, Default value: 1 

yes there was the good php_xdebug.dll coming with xampp 

so use it and dont look far :) maybe that will help you

Answer (score 0):

it might be also the matter of relative addressing due to portable xampp.
you can change your Xdebug addresses like this.

before

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
```

after

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
```

Comment: Re-read the question, they were clearly using fully-qualified absolute paths, so it’s not a relative-path problem.